# The getter 'key' was called on null while using Carousel on latest version of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, carousel

I'm getting this exception on `Carousel` after updating flutter to the latest version. `Carousel` was working fine on flutter version 1.22.4.  But upon switching to latest version (2.0.3), I'm getting this exception. Below are the code and exception. I'm using the below package
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro

**Exception**

> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library
> ═════════════════════════════════
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during performLayout():
> The getter 'key' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: key
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was Carousel
> lib\…\homeViews\homeAppBarDelegate.dart:39 When the exception was
> thrown, this was the stack
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
> #1      SliverChildListDelegate.build package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:722
> #2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1201
> #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild. package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1214
> #4      BuildOwner.buildScope package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2647 ... The following
> RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
> RenderSliverFillViewport#4a87d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> NEEDS-PAINT RenderObject: RenderSliverFillViewport#4a87d
> relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
> constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle, scrollOffset: 0.0,
> remainingPaintExtent: 411.4, crossAxisExtent: 230.0,
> crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 411.4,
> remainingCacheExtent: 411.4, cacheOrigin: 0.0)
> geometry: null
> no children current live ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

**Code**

```dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      ...................
Stack(
    children: [
        CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
           SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: HomeAppBarDelegate(
                    maxExtent: 230,
                    minExtent: 50,
                ),
                pinned: true,
                floating: false,
             ),
          ],
       ),
    ],
   ),
),    
},
}
```

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';

class HomeAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {

return Stack(
     children: [
      ...................

        // ------------------------------ C O V E R   B L U R   I M A G E S
        Carousel(
           animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuint,
           animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
           dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
           overlayShadow: true,
           autoplayDuration: Duration(seconds: 4),
           showIndicator: false,
           dotIncreasedColor: Colors.brown,
           onImageChange: (prevInd, currInd) => coverImgIndex = currInd,
           images: [
              ...coverImagesList.map(
                (singleImg) => HomeBlurCoverImg(
                 imgURl: singleImg,
                 animationVal: animationVal,
                 maxExtent: maxExtent,
                 sizingInformation: sizingInformation,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Getting blank screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying `geometry: null no children current live`.
You widget isn't receiving any children, can you confirm that this is not the issue? Populate your items before running the widget, or check using `isNotEmpty` before rendering it, that should solve your problem.
Specifically `coverImagesList`, I can't see where you are passing the values of this list or where your widget tree is getting it from.

Comment: yup that's exactly what it was. Thanks